# How to express pivot table value as percentage of column total in App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I've got the code to express my spreadsheet data in a pivot table, but I need the values to show as a percentage of column total. It seems that there's a property to achieve that result, but I don't know how to integrate that into the script.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/pivot-value-display-type

```
    function addPivotTable3(spreadsheetId3, pivotSourceDataSheetId3, destinationSheetId3) 
{
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var sheetName = "Sheet3";

  var pivotTableParams = {};

  // The source indicates the range of data you want to put in the table.
  // optional arguments: startRowIndex, startColumnIndex, endRowIndex, endColumnIndex
  pivotTableParams.source = {
    sheetId: ss.getSheetByName(sheetName).getSheetId()
  };

  // Group rows, the 'sourceColumnOffset' corresponds to the column number in the source range
  // eg: 0 to group by the first column
  pivotTableParams.rows = [{
    sourceColumnOffset: 2,
    sortOrder: "ASCENDING"
  }];

  // Defines how a value in a pivot table should be calculated.
  pivotTableParams.values = [{
    summarizeFunction: "SUM",
        displayType: "PERCENT_OF_COLUMN_TOTAL",     
    sourceColumnOffset: 3
  }];


  var requests = [{
    'updateCells': {
      'rows': {
        'values': [
          {
            'pivotTable': {
              'source': {
                'sheetId': pivotSourceDataSheetId3,
                'startRowIndex': 0,
                'startColumnIndex': 0,
                'endRowIndex': 94,
                'endColumnIndex': 4,
              },
              'rows': [
                {
                  'sourceColumnOffset': 2,
                  'showTotals': true,
                  'sortOrder': 'ASCENDING',
                  'valueBucket': {
                    'buckets': [
                      {
                        'stringValue': 'BAE Stages',
                      },
                    ],
                  },
                },
                      {
                  'sourceColumnOffset': 94,
                  'showTotals': true,
                  'sortOrder': 'ASCENDING',
                  'valueBucket': {},
                },
              ],
              'columns': [
                {
                  'sourceColumnOffset': 0,
                  'sortOrder': 'ASCENDING',
                  'showTotals': true,
                  'valueBucket': {},
                },
              ],
              'values': [
                {
                  'summarizeFunction': "SUM",
                  'sourceColumnOffset': 3,
                  //'displayType': "PERCENT_OF_COLUMN_TOTAL",
                  //This line triggers a JSON erorr


                },
              ],
              'valueLayout': 'HORIZONTAL', 

            },

          },
        ],
      },
      'start': {
        'sheetId': destinationSheetId3,
        'rowIndex': 0,
        'columnIndex': 0,
      },
      'fields': 'pivotTable',
    },
  }];

  var response =
      Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({'requests': requests}, spreadsheetId3);

}
```

Comment: When working with new API endpoints, use the Google APIs Explorer to interactively build valid request bodies. It includes hover tooltips and a "fields" generator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I didn't know either and the documentation is soooooo mysterious.

I was about to give up then I came across this: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#PivotValueCalculatedDisplayType

Eventually I worked out your line should be:

```
              'calculatedDisplayType' : "PERCENT_OF_COLUMN_TOTAL",
```

(On the above webpage is `PivotValueCalculatedDisplayType`  and within the table is the ENUM you mentioned, "PERCENT_OF_COLUMN_TOTAL"
I had a hunch that since we are in pivot table/value part of the object, we don't need the PivotValue  ... so we're left with calculatedDisplayType.

Phew.

Comment: You can interactively build valid request json in the Google APIs Explorer. IMO the API description of the requests and resources is pretty straightforward. Can you share a better API description?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about Google APIs Explorer - I can see that they document the Google Sheets v4 API

Comment: Omg that works! Thanks David! Would never have thought of that.